# Use HtmlHelper to add attribute for html tags, CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a project with cakephp right now. And I am wondering if there is a way to add attribute for a `img` tag, this is in my view:

Here is my code:

```
echo '<img id="image">';
echo $this->Js->get('#image', 
                     array('htmlAttributes' => array('src' => 'somesourcehere')));
```

Edit:

I found another way to do this without using JsHelper, but use HtmlHelper,

```
echo $this->Html->image('somesourcehere',array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));
```

But the issue is the `src` attribute would be `url` like, while I was trying to set the `src` as `base64` data, so it would be something like this in HTML

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

However, I can only get

```
<img src="/img/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `/img/`part in my `src` ? So I can make the image show up

**Update**
I am too dumb, only need to do

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$source.'">';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP Html image method produce relative or absolute src path to images.

In your case if need to use Helper, then use **[HtmlHelper method called tag](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::tag)**:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->tag(
        'img', 
         null, 
         array(
            'id' => 'image',
            'src' => 'data:image/png;base64,'.$source'
        )
   );
?>
```

or just simple combine html and php:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo $source; ?>">
```